# Seeing what tickets were closed between two builds

Tags: build-process, agile, changelog

How can I find out which tickets were closed between one build and the previous stable build? I'm trying to design a new build process, so I'm not set on particular tools yet. Which ones would let me see this sort of info in a dashboard, if any? Should I try to do this from a bug tracker, or from a build pipeline such as Jenkins or Bamboo, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

A possible set-up is to:

- include the bug-tracker issue ID in your commit messages in your SCM ("[MYPROJECT-12923] add this new option in that nice feature")
- launch your build with Jenkins that retrieves the source code from your SCM. Jenkins will show you a "Recent Changes" label linking to a page where you will find the commits that took place between last build and the current one. The commit messages will include the list of issues ID included in the build.

Note: that maybe does not answer your question perfectly because those commits could be intermediate one. Depends also on how granular are the commits.

Answer (score 2):

1. In our DEV team, all the commits have the JIRA number in them (This is enforced by a plugin called `TicketIt` in Stash . There are various other plugins available for different repositories) . When we run a build , all commits that are part of the build are aggregrated by teamcity and displayed on a tab called `issues` . This solution that I am proposing works in teamcity and bamboo . I am sure thee would be some plugin with Jenkins for the same.
2. A hackier way would be to get the start time of the last build (x) and the current build(y) and get all JIRA tickets that were closed during this time via JIRA API. This  might not be a foolproof method if your JIRA's are not always closed before a build